# G150XG01 LCD not working

Tags: pi-4, display, lcd

I have an [AU Optronics G150XG01 LCD screen](https://www.ebay.com/itm/163055626454) and a [controller card](https://www.ebay.com/itm/362288761416) to go with it. I am connecting it to a Raspberry Pi with an HDMI cable. I started it up and it looked very distorted. I read online that it can be caused by HDMI problems.

However, when I turned off and on the board, only the grayish-white backlight came on. I have no idea how to make it work now. I have tried turning it on and off several times, no luck. I disconnected all the cables from the LCD and reconnected it and had the same problem.

Could I accidently have ESD fried the board?? I am slightly panicked as I need this soon for a DIY project.

Comment: maybe one of the sonnections is bad

Comment: the answer to your only question is `yes` ... it cannot possibly have any other answer